# Is it possible to export many partitions in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to export many partitions from one table in one EXPORT?

[Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport) says:

```
EXPORT TABLE tablename [PARTITION (part_column="value"[, ...])]
  TO 'export_target_path'
```

And I suppose `[, ...]` means additional partition columns:  `part_column1="value", part_column2="value"` not different values for the same partition column.

Is it possible to use one column with many values? i mean something like this:
`part_column1 = "value1","value2"` or `part_column1 = "value1", part_column1 = "value2"` ?

[EDIT]
My example is:

```
hive (pr)> export table account partition (start_date="2015-06-23",start_date="2015-06-22") to 'accounts';
Copying data from file:/tmp/hive_2015-07-02_17-40-50_937_3732031090994168422-1/-local-10000/_metadata
Copying file: file:/tmp/hive_2015-07-02_17-40-50_937_3732031090994168422-1/-local-10000/_metadata
Copying data from hdfs://server.pl:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/pr.db/account/start_date=2015-06-22
Copying file: hdfs://server.pl:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/pr.db/account/start_date=2015-06-22/000000_0
Copying file: hdfs://server.pl:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/pr.db/account/start_date=2015-06-22/000001_0
Copying file: hdfs://server.pl:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/pr.db/account/start_date=2015-06-22/000002_0
OK
Time taken: 20.69 seconds
```

So I wanted to export two partitions: start_date="2015-06-23",start_date="2015-06-22" and only partition start_date="2015-06-22" was exported

Pawel

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it as of Hive 0.14. Trying to specify 2 parttions will create only one folder in target directory with data from one partition.

Answer (score 0):

Well the documentation example clearly said that you can do for two columns

```
export table employee partition (emp_country="in", emp_state="ka") to 'hdfs_exports_location/employee';
```

So when you can get the above working, you can also get the following. Were you facing any error

```
export table employee partition (emp_country="in", emp_country="us") to 'hdfs_exports_location/employee';
```

Comment: Documentation says I can do for two columns, but example provides two DIFFERENT columns. If I want to use column twice with different values it exports only the last partition provided in the brackets.

Comment: so in the above example, only emp_country="us" is exported and "in" is skipped. Is that your output? And you need to export both us and in correct

Comment: I don't know cause i haven't check it. It's not my case. I have two different values for the same column. In the example from documentation, there are two different columns. I have added my real case in the question.